# How to insert different values into db with input name="value[]"

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have a question, I'm actually trying to do an e-commerce website under Laravel.
So heres my problem :
I try to fetch all ordered products with quantity etc
My form is like this :

```
@foreach($cartCollection as $item)
                {{ $item->name }}<br />
                {{ __('home.quantity') }} : {{ $item->quantity }}<br />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="{{ $item->id }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="{{ $item->quantity }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="size[]" value="{{$item->attributes->size}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="{{$item->price}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="priceItem" value="{{ \Cart::get($item->id)->getPriceSum() }}">
                {{ \Cart::get($item->id)->getPriceSum() }} €<br />
@endforeach
```

And my Controller:

```
 foreach($request->product_id as $product){
              foreach($request->size as $size){
                  foreach($request->price as $price){
                    $orderedProducts = new OrderedProduct;
                    $orderedProducts->product_id = $product;
                    $orderedProducts->order_id = $order->id;
                    $orderedProducts->quantity = $request->quantity;
                    $orderedProducts->price    = $price;
                    $orderedProducts->size     = $size;
                    $orderedProducts->save();
                  }
              }
          }
```

With this, it create and duplicate the product, like if I got 2 sizes for 2 different product, it create it 4 times into the db instead of 2 (one product ID with one size and the other product with the other size), do you have anysolution ?

Comment: Did you double-check your loop, looks like the nested loop is causing the issue.

Comment: You can use `UpdateOrCreate` method, where your `product_id` should be unique. If `product _id` not in table, then it will create. If already exists then it will update

Comment: Btw, you use all  dynamic array input, instead of `quantity` and `priceItem`„ but why?

Comment: Well, I'm agree with the nested loop, I already try without using this kind of loop, but when I'm doing it, for exemple, I've got a product with 30 as size and another with 80, it create 2 products as expected but both with the same size.

UpdateOrCreate method, I'm not sure about it as my product_id is not unique, for exemple, the only "thing" unique is the order_id as the product is related to the order_id. And the product_id is a foreign key to the products table.
```quantity``` and ```priceItem``` are used into something else for the checkout

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, I found the solution here it is if it can help some of you :

```
          foreach($request->product_id as $key => $product){
                    $orderedProducts = new OrderedProduct;
                    $orderedProducts->product_id = $product;
                    $orderedProducts->order_id = $order->id;
                    $orderedProducts->quantity = $request->quantity;
                    $orderedProducts->price    = $request->price[$key];
                    $orderedProducts->size     = $request->size[$key];
                    $orderedProducts->save();
          }
```

So i just change my controller and now it works great ! Thanks the community for your help